# What type of wood is suitable for fascia?

Tags: wood, trim, carpentry, trim-carpentry

I'm replacing some fascia boards, I am looking for something that is rot-resistant but I am hesitant to use pressure treated lumber due to shrinkage as it dries out and I don't want gaps (project has to be done over a few days).

What are some good wood alternatives that are competitive in terms of price/performance? Hopefully I am not asking for too much, but if you could list the alternatives in terms of relative price that would be awesome.

Comment: Yeah, I'd shy away from PT as well, you are not likely to find the size you need anyway.  How about PVC, or are you specifically looking for a wood product?

Comment: Are you opposed to steel wraps? They're very easy to install over pine or plywood fascia.

Comment: The trim look can't be changed due to HOA, not to mention the fascia is "stepped" with a 1x4 over 1x6 over a 2x8. PVC is too expensive and wouldn't match the grain of the rest even after painting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cedar is what I have used because it is very good at rot resistance,  fascia boards especially with gutters attached are one of the places in a home I usually find rot if your budget allows redwood is even better but cost more.

Comment: Cedar is especially long lasting if pre-primed prior to installation...but be careful about tannin oil.

Comment: I am looking to replace all the 28 year old trim on my house, including fascias behind gutters, with the artificial stuff that home depot carries.  Had the trim around the garage door done with it last summer, it looks good. Not sure what it's called, and can't access the website at the moment.

Comment: Yea I did some research, and looked at the wood used here that held up for the past 40 years and cedar seems like the best option. Thanks ;) and @LeeSam I heard about that too so I am going to prime it with an oil based blocker from killz

Comment: @CrossRoads Yes, I like the “Fiber Cement sidings and trim” too. (Also called composite siding / trim.) it is more stable than cedar or redwood, but must be painted. The paint must be “cement “ compatible. You can get it in various textures: smooth, wood grain, etc.

Comment: On my last home I used hardy plank and after having 2 of the very expensive trim boards break took the rest back and got cedar. I like the siding but not the trim.